# Calling a Class Method on a Module

Tags: ruby, modules

I have a module (in file dialect.rb) defined as such:

```
require 'dialect/generators/elements'

module Dialect
  def self.included(caller)
    caller.extend Dialect::Generator::Element
  end

  def self.version
    "Dialect v#{Dialect::VERSION}"
  end
end
```

Then I have the file dialect/generators/elements.rb, which looks like this:

```
module Dialect
  module Generator
    module Element

      puts Dialect.version

    end
  end
end
```

If I run my app, I get:

```
/lib/dialect/generators/elements.rb:7:in `<module:Element>':
undefined method `version' for Dialect:Module (NoMethodError)
```

My question/problem is: I didn't understand why the Element module could not find the version method here.

How I call Dialect is like this:

```
require 'dialect'

class PageTest
  include Dialect
end
```

So you can see Dialect is mixed-in to an existing class. It's when this class is instantiated that I get the error above.

When I try a simple IRB session doing what appears to be this same logic, this all seems to work:

```
irb(main):001:0> module Dialect
irb(main):002:1>   def self.version
irb(main):003:2>     puts "Version number"
irb(main):004:2>   end
irb(main):005:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> module Dialect
irb(main):007:1>   module Generator
irb(main):008:2>     module Element
irb(main):009:3>       puts Dialect.version
irb(main):010:3>     end
irb(main):011:2>   end
irb(main):012:1> end
Version number
```

Here I get the "Version number" text back, which tells me (I think?) that Dialect::Generator::Element can call the method version on Dialect.

The issue ended up being corrected by simply moving my require statement to the end, like this:

```
module Dialect
  def self.included(caller)
    caller.extend Dialect::Generator::Element
  end

  def self.version
    "Dialect v#{Dialect::VERSION}"
  end
end

require 'dialect/generators/elements'
```

Having the require statement at the end solves the problem I was having.

The question then becomes: is this a good way to do this? I feel like making my logic depend on where the require statement goes seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

The `require` line in the first file means that ruby runs the *second* file before the first file, which is *before* the `version` method is declared...

Doing it the other way around will work, since only when  `included` is called is the module `Element` is required.

dialect/dialect.rb:

```
module Dialect
  def self.included(caller)
    caller.extend Dialect::Generator::Element
  end

  def self.version
    "Dialect v#{Dialect::VERSION}"
  end
end
```

dialect/generators/elements.rb:

```
require 'dialect/dialect'

module Dialect
  module Generator
    module Element

      puts Dialect.version

    end
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you could also write a file declaring only the version:

dialect/version.rb:

```
module Dialect   
  def self.version
    "Dialect v#{Dialect::VERSION}"
  end
end
```

**Edit**

To answer your question - this is *not* a good way to do this. The problem you encountered with the `require` hints to *circular dependency* - `Dialect` calls `Element`, which uses `Dialect` on its creation.

The correct resolution is to break this dependency by using my `version.rb` suggestion above, so the code will look like this:

dialect/version.rb:

```
module Dialect   
  def self.version
    "Dialect v#{Dialect::VERSION}"
  end
end
```

dialect/generators/elements.rb:

```
require 'dialect/version'

module Dialect
  module Generator
    module Element

      puts Dialect.version

    end
  end
end
```

dialect/dialect.rb:

```
require 'dialect/version'
require 'dialect/generators/elements'

module Dialect
  def self.included(caller)
    caller.extend Dialect::Generator::Element
  end
end
```